# Parsing XML and checking for Null value in XSL document

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I am parsing some XML in the following format:

```
<J_TITLE>
<DATA pid="1"><xsl:value-of select = "//TITLE"/></DATA>
<DATA pid="3"><xsl:value-of select = "//TITLE_FOR_3"/></DATA>
</J_TITLE>
```

What I would like to do is check if TITLE_FOR_3 is null. If it is change the value to something else for DATA pid = 3.

I have tried to complete the following but this is not working:

```
<JPM_TITLE>
    <DATA pid="1"><xsl:value-of select = "//TITLE"/></DATA>

    <xsl:value-of select = "//TITLE_FOR_3"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($NorTitle)!=0">
          <DATA pid="3"><xsl:value-of select = "//TITLE"/></DATA>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <DATA pid="3"><xsl:value-of select = "//TITLE_FOR_3"/></DATA>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</JPM_TITLE>
```

The above has changed slightly from my original test. How do I name the value-of- select part so that I can do the string length check?  Or how can I pass the value of this into the string length check?

Comment: i think you want to use the "xsl:vaiable" instead of 'xsl:value-of'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="NorTitle" select = "//TITLE_FOR_3"/>
```

..and as Marcus correctly point out, do the test as:

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space($NorTitle))!=0">
```

or:

```
<xsl:when test="string(normalize-space($NorTitle))">
```

(in XPath a string is 'true' when it is non-empty)

Comment: In string comparisons for equality, inequality or length it is often advisable to use `normalize-space()` to cut of leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @MarcusRickert - Thanks Marcus in this case the value from //TITLE_FOR_3 is already trimmed from whitespace beforehand.